# Randomize multiple Stringlists

Tags: delphi, random, delphi-7

I want to randomize a number of string lists.

The string lists all contain the same number of items, and I wish to apply the same shuffle to each list. So if `List1[0]` is swapped with `List1[7]`, then I want to swap `List2[0]` with `List2[7]`, and so on for all the lists.

Comment: Please could you edit your question to be more clear. Sorry, I didn't understand what you want to do. What about the 3rd and 4th lists?

Comment: I will try but it is difficult

Comment: you should simple post sample content of the lists before and after shuffle

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just shuffle one list and then assign it's contents to the other lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to consider the case where you have two lists. I'll leave it up to you to generalise the ideas to handle more than two lists. The key understanding is best gained using the most simple case where there are two lists.

I would solve the problem like this:

1. Generating a permutation of the integers 0, 1, ... N-1. Use the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to achieve this.
2. Using that permutation to shuffle both lists.

The key is to use the same permutation to shuffle both lists.

```
type
  TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

procedure Swap(var i1, i2: Integer); overload;
var
  tmp: Integer;
begin
  tmp := i1;
  i1 := i2;
  i2 := tmp;
end;

function GeneratePermutation(Count: Integer): TIntegerArray;
//Fisher-Yates shuffle
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Count);
  for i := 0 to Count-1 do
    Result[i] := i;
  for i := Count-1 downto 1 do begin
    j := Random(i+1);
    Swap(Result[i], Result[j]);
  end;
end;

procedure ApplyPermutation(List: TStringList; 
  const Permutation: TIntegerArray);
var
  i: Integer;
  Temp: TStringList;
begin
  Assert(List.Count=Length(Permutation));
  Temp := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Temp.Assign(List);
    for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      List[i] := Temp[Permutation[i]];
  finally
    Temp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And then you can apply to your situation like this:

```
Permutation := GeneratePermutation(List1.Count);
Apply(List1, Permutation);
Apply(List2, Permutation);
```

This is an exceedingly general solution that can be extended to more than two lists, and can be applied to other data types. If you want a very short and simple dedicated routine then you can do it like this:

```
procedure PermuteListsInTandem(List1, List2: TStringList);
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Assert(List1.Count=List2.Count);
  for i := List1.Count-1 downto 1 do begin
    j := Random(i+1);
    List1.Exchange(i, j);
    List2.Exchange(i, j);
  end;
end;
```

I'm struggling to think of a good name for this procedure. Can anyone help me out by offering something better?

Comment: +1 as an extension to this you can build a procedure with a dynamic array containing the TStringList's. But the basic is shown

Comment: what about SynchronListPermutation